# Showing div on scroll up but hide near top of page

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to show a div when scrolling up on the page and hiding when scrolling down. It works as expected, but I also want to hide the div 100px from the top of the page so it doesn't overlap my header. How can I adjust this code (or use different code, better with jquery maybe?) to do this?

Thanks for any help.

```
// Hide Header on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('#fixed header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
}
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('#fixed header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('#fixed header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to make a cleaner version of this code. The interval isn't really necessary and is just draining resources from the browser for no reason. You can write it a lot shorter like this.

Using JQuery:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var navbarHeight = $('#fixed-header').outerHeight();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  //Scrolling Down or scrolled too far up
  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop || scrollTop < navbarHeight) {
    $('#fixed-header').hide();
  } else {
    //Scrolling Up
    $('#fixed-header').show();
  }
  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: red; width: 100%; position: fixed;" id="fixed-header">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
```

Using plain old JavaScript:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
  var navbarHeight = document.getElementById('fixed-header').offsetHeight;

  // Scrolling down or scrolled to far up
  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop || scrollTop < navbarHeight) {
    document.getElementById('fixed-header').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    //Scrolling Up
    document.getElementById('fixed-header').style.display = 'block';
  }
  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
};
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: red; width: 100%; position: fixed;" id="fixed-header">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ut iuvaret volumus, ancillae expetenda cu sit. Eu ius tollit labores, ferri scripserit vel te. Stet bonorum quaerendum mea no, constituto sadipscing ad qui. Eu sale cotidieque vis, at velit impetus pro. Soluta legendos qui eu, ex duo tota repudiare. Ut magna omnes legendos eos, in quando laudem tacimates his.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Gilles. I'm pretty useless at code, but how would I then hide the div 100px from the top of the page using your code?

Comment: It's already in there 
if(scrollTop > lastScrollTop || scrollTop < navbarHeight)
It will hide the fixed header (by the way, you can't have spaces in an ID name usually) when you are scrolling down OR when you are less than the height of your navbar from the top.

Comment: Thanks very much Gilles, I appreciate your help.